# PHP script to query unixODBC fails in browser but works from Linux command prompt

Tags: php, apache, odbc, centos7

I have unixODBC set up correctly on my CentOS7 server to work with my Transoft ODBC driver, and I can successfully connect and query the databases I am trying to hit using it in root with the command:

```
isql -v 'DSN' 'user' 'pwd'
```

I took the next step and created a PHP script to run a query.

```
$connect = odbc_connect("integra.udd","user","pwd");
$query = "SELECT Company1,Product,Vendor,Description1 FROM ICMAST WHERE Company1=1 LIMIT 5";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
  $product = odbc_result($result, 2);
  $desc = odbc_result($result, 4);
  print "\n$product $desc<br />";
}
```

If I execute this in root using `PHP odbctest.php`, it works and I get the results I should. Furthermore, I can drop to the apache user with `su -s /bin/bash apache` and run it, and it works. (I verified that the Apache server uses `apache` as the user by running the command `echo exec ('whoami');` in a PHP script)

However, if I go to a browser and run it, I get the following error:

> `Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/html/2m/odbctest.php on line 10`

The shared object file is not found when running with Apache, but when running from any user, it is.

First, I assumed a permissions issue, so I changed ownership of the `libtsodbc.so` file to `apache:apache`. No change.

Then I checked permissions on the file, it's set to `555`, so should be executable by users.

I then tried a PHP script run in a browser that checks if the file exists in that path. Here is the script I ran:

```
<?php
$filename = '/usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

It returned that the file exists, so PHP can see it even when Apache is executing the script.

I discarded the idea that it is a SELinux or Firewalled thing as it doesn't even get to the point where it is trying to connect, it fails when it tries to find the shared object library file. So the issue has to be internal on the server.

Finally, I thought maybe this had to do with the shared library path, even though it is looking at the actual path to the file in the error and not finding it. So I tried adding the following line to my PHP script to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/usql/sqlaccess/");
```

No change, still gives the file not found error.

I'm sure it is something simple as I am a total Linux beginner, but I am at a loss as to what to try next. Any ideas? What else is different between a user running a PHP script and Apache running a PHP script?

**Edit to add**
`libtsodbc.so`, `php`, and `httpd` file command output:

```
[root@intranetserver /]# file /usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so
/usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
[root@intranetserver /]# file /usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=70ddc88b357d818240da4d4b3db50790c7913822, stripped
[root@intranetserver /]# file /usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0890c878aa1d1a620d5c65d25a13d11cc2fdf96a, stripped
```

Comment: any luck? I have the exact same problem; I can run the php script from the terminal but not from apache... looking into phpinfo() they both use the same php.ini

Comment: @A.JAlhorr - A new question is probably appropriate for you. Full output of `phpinfo()` is likely to be necessary to make further progress on it. (Guidance under [Checking your PHP installation](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/IODBCPHPHOWTO#Checking%20your%20PHP%20installation).)  User `apache` needs read and execute permissions on all relevant libraries including `libtsodbc.so` (so perhaps provide the `ls -l /usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so` output).

Comment: @TallTed thank you very much for your response; I in fact already have a question on stack overflow and edited it to include all that you have suggested  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142353/cannot-connect-to-informix-through-odbc-on-linux-machine

Comment: Appears likely this old question would be answered by the new one -- that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting needs to go into the `httpd` config.

Answer (score 2):

Looks likely to a bitness mismatch to me.

Check output of these commands.  They should all match --

```
file /usr/usql/sqlaccess/libtsodbc.so

file `which php`      # the runtime PHP

file `which httpd`    # the typical name of the apache executable

find / -name mod_php -exec file {} \;    
     # mod_php is the PHP module for Apache
     # if you know where mod_php is on your box, you can just do
     #     file /path/to/mod_php
```

Comment: I originally suspected a mismatch too, particularly since when setting up the unixODBC, the libtsodbc.so file I had was 32 bit and I had a similar error (file not found), so I had to get a 64 bit driver from Transoft.  When I was able to successfully run the php script at the command prompt, I knew php was 64 bit as well, but I wasn't sure about httpd.  I ran the file command on all three and they are all ELF 64-bit LSB shared object files.

Comment: I found the mod_php5 executable at /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so.  When I ran the file command, it shows the same as the above: 64 bit.  The upside is that in researching this I am learning a lot about how Apache runs PHP.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran an exec('whoami') on both the terminal and the apache; the apache returns apache and the terminal retuens root... Unfortunately changing the driver permissions to apache does not work and changing the user to root in httpd.conf gives errors when I try to start apache...

Comment: Executing things through the command-line `php` is very different than executing things through `apache` and the `mod_php5` module. Comparing `php_info()` output for these can be a useful step when issues are seen with one or the other (`php` or `mod_php5`) and not both.