# Cannot Connect to informix through ODBC on linux machine

Tags: php, odbc, centos7, informix

I am woking on a virtual machine operating CentOS 7, and I am trying to connect to an Informix database using ODBC (unixODBC)  through some php.

I am using php7.0 and I have installed the unixODBC-2.3.7 as well as installed the informix sdk package (iif.12.10.FC12DE.linux-x86_64).

I have configures the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini as such:

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER=Installed
[IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER]
Driver=/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Setup=/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=03.80
FileUsage=0
SQLLevel=1
smProcessPerConnect=Y
```

odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
informix_db=IBM INFORMIXODBC DRIVER

[informix_db]
Driver=/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
HostName=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Service=xxxx
Database=xxx
LogonID=xxx
pwd=xxx
ServerName=xxx
Client_Locale=xxx
DB_Locale=xxx
```

I then set-up the environment variables with the following commands:

```
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle
export INFORMIXSERVER=xxx
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INFORMIXDIR}/lib/cli
```

My php code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$dbUserName=xxx;
$dbPassword=xxx;
$conn=odbc_connect("Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};HOSTNAME=xxx;Database=xxx;PORT=xxx;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;", $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
 if (!$conn)
 {
    echo odbc_errormsg();
 }
 else {
    $sql="{CALL somequery}";
    $res=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    odbc_result_all($res);
 }
?>
```

Unfortunately when I run the php I get the following error:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle/lib/cli/iclis09b.so' : file not found
```

I have read on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606832/r-unixodbcdriver-managercant-open-lib-sql-server-file-not-found) that this might be cause by the DriverVersion being wrong so I tried both 03.80 and 02.70 (the odbc installed with php and the unixODBC) inside odbcinst.ini.

I am fairly new to linux and can't tell what other problem might be causing it? Maybe I'm setting the environment variable false?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Using the isql command worked after I tried the following:
-Adding the following environment variables: `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` `CLIENT_LOCALE` `DB_LOCALE` `ODBCINI` `ONCONFIG`
-Adding the onconfig file and configuring it.
-Adding the sqlhosts file and configuring it.

Still figuring out how to make the php code work (still giving the same error)

Hope that helps.

**EDIT#2**
Running the php through the terminal works and and I can successfully query the informix database with the previous database, it only does not work when I call the php code through the browser (using apache).

As suggested by someone on a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025977/php-script-to-query-unixodbc-fails-in-browser-but-works-from-linux-command-promp?noredirect=1#comment97227659_39025977), here is the results yielded by running `ls -l` in the directory where the driver libraries are located:

```
[root@administration-pc cli]# ls -l
total 21748
-rwxr-xr-x 3 informix informix 1865750 Jun 25  2018 iclis09b.so
-rwxrwxrwx 3 informix informix 1907069 Jun 25  2018 iclit09b.so
-rwxr-xr-x 2 informix informix   32805 Jun 25  2018 idmrs09a.so
-rw-r--r-- 2 informix informix 3595434 Jun 25  2018 libcli.a
-rw-r--r-- 2 informix informix   32864 Jun 25  2018 libdmr.a
-rw-r--r-- 2 informix informix 3595434 Jun 25  2018 libifcli.a
-rwxr-xr-x 3 informix informix 1865750 Jun 25  2018 libifcli.so
-rw-r--r-- 2 informix informix   32864 Jun 25  2018 libifdmr.a
-rwxr-xr-x 2 informix informix   32805 Jun 25  2018 libifdmr.so
-rwxr-xr-x 3 informix informix 1865750 Jun 25  2018 libixcli.so
-rwxrwxrwx 3 informix informix 1907069 Jun 25  2018 libtcli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 informix informix 3593510 Jun 25  2018 libthcli.a
-rwxrwxrwx 3 informix informix 1907069 Jun 25  2018 libthcli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root           8 Mar 13 16:22 sample.txt
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8yQN.jpg) is result of phpinfo() for apache; and [here](https://pastebin.com/bxKmedCK) the one for php running through the terminal.

I also ran `exec('whoami')` for both, and apache returns `apache` while the terminal returns `root`.

I tried changing the `httpd.conf` so that `User` is `root` instead of `apache` does let me start apache anymore.

Also changing the permissions of the `iclis09b.so` to apache does not seem to work.

**EDIT#3(Solution)**

Apache apparently does not have access to the environment variables, so you have to add all the environment variables to it...

Mine were located in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` ...

Comment: you can try as informix user the isql tool included in the odbc manager: isql -v databasename to verify the configuration. May php is started with user with no access right to the informix dir.

Comment: Need to include cli and esql in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For example : LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/informix/ids1210fc10/lib:/opt/ibm/informix/ids1210fc10/lib/esql:/opt/ibm/informix/ids1210fc10/lib/cli

Comment: @jacques yes I tried it, and it gives me the same error... but I did try to just read with php from the same directory where the library is and it did let me with a simple file_get_content; so Im assuming its not a permission problem? Im really bad with linux :/

Comment: and yes I did try including thecli and esql path...

Comment: I have noticed that once I added those path, the isql -v command now returns `[IM002][unixODBC][Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Data source not found and no default driver specified.` `[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect` even though both odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini are configured in the etc/ and unixODBC directories... do I have to configure one in the informix directory?

Comment: @A.JAlhorr - You should not accept an answer that doesn't actually solve your problem. Better to write your own answer, that *does* solve your problem, and accept that. The short-form is that when running as a CGI (which `mod_php` does), you have to use `setenv` calls to set necessary environment variables either in your Apache `httpd.conf` or directly within your php scripts. (Note that comparing your `php_info` outputs shows `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set for commandline `php` and not for `apache` with `mod_php`...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the reference snippet you have mention is pointing to a direct usage of Informix ODBC driver, that is perfectly fine. I couldn't find any problem with the snippet that can lead to the error you are getting. At this moment I am bit puzzled about the error text snippet **[unixODBC][Driver Manager]**. I mean, the unixODBC Driver Manager should not come to picture when the application makes a direct reference to Informix ODBC driver. Can you please try **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** with the following value?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INFORMIXDIR}/lib:${INFORMIXDIR}/lib/esql:${INFORMIXDIR}/lib/cli
```

FYI: Since you have created a DSN (with the INI file), you could just specify the DSN name in the connection string used by the PHP application, for example:

```
"DSN=informix_db; uid=xxx; pwd=xxxx;"
```

In case if you would like to try troubleshoot  with a pure ODBC sample application connection (I mean outside of PHP environment), then here is the ODBC application sample code.
https://github.com/OpenInformix/ODBCExamples/blob/master/src/IfxOdbcSample1.c

https://github.com/OpenInformix/ODBCExamples/blob/master/src/odbc.ini

https://github.com/OpenInformix/ODBCExamples/blob/master/src/makefile

https://github.com/OpenInformix/ODBCExamples/blob/master/src/envc.bsh

Comment: Hello, thank you for all your help, I have tried the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it is not working :/ I just found out that I might have been using the wrong odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini; Im using the files located directly in the etc/ directory and not the ones inside the unixODBC folder, Im guessing they are the ones for the php ODBC? As for the DSN file, I did not quite understand, should I put the dsn uid and pwd inside the odbc.ini under the [informix_db]? I have tried to use the isql -v command from the terminal but it gives me the exact same error. I guess I will try to troubleshoot it

Comment: using your ODBC sample application. Anyway, thank you a lot for your help

Comment: You may specify uid and pwd inside the INI file, and it is only a matter of choice. If you specify all properties inside the INI file, then you just need to specify only the DSN name in the connection string.  "DSN=informix_db".  By any chance if you have specified a property both in INI and connection string then the property on the connection string will take precedence (and ignore the same property specified on the INI file.)

Comment: @Satyan - The ODBC Driver Manager is always in the picture if the ODBC application is built with linkage to it, no matter whether the ODBC app uses a connect string that is DSN-less or DSN-full. This is actually a benefit of building a DBMS-agnostic ODBC-based app, because the Driver Manager can handle a number of translations (between ODBC versions, Unicode encodings, and other things), removing such responsibility from both app and driver.

Comment: @A.JAlhorr - You may want to work with a single set of `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files, typically in `/etc/`, with symlinks from any other current location. You can usually blend the content of multiple existing files. You can often also tell applications to use specific files (over-riding those at the default locations like `/etc/odbc.ini` or `~/.odbc.ini`) via the `$ODBCINI` and `$ODBCINSTINI` environment variables